# Determine if the given integral is convergent

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}{\log x\over x^a}\,\mathrm dx,\quad a<1$$

I tried solving using the $\mu-test$. so if I consider $\mu=1$ then

$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} {x\log x\over x^a}$ Solving further, I get a limit $0$, so the integral must be divergent. But according to the book it is convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For any $\varepsilon>0$ we have $x^{\varepsilon}\log x \to 0$ as $x \to +0$. Let $\varepsilon := \dfrac{1-a}{2}$, write $\dfrac{\log x}{x^a} = \dfrac{x^\varepsilon \log x}{x^{a+\varepsilon}}$ and compare with $\int_0^{\pi/2} \dfrac{dx}{x^{a+\varepsilon}}$.

Comment: okie, if $a=-5, \alpha =3$ then the integral should be divergent by this test ?

Comment: yeah, makes sense now. what is wrong with the $\mu-test$ then ?

Comment: For negative $a$ you don't need anything else, because the integrand becomes continuous. Comparison test is needed only for $0\le a<1$.

Comment: the second integral you suggested would converge for $a+\epsilon<1 \implies \epsilon<1-a$, as $a<1$ $\epsilon$ can actually be equal to 1. It will fail again. Please correct me

Comment: But $a+\frac{1-a}{2} < 1$.

Comment: i got it, Thanks 1!!!!

Comment: BTW is there another name for the $\mu-test$ that is more common ? I am trying to look for its definition button cannot find it anywhere on the internet.

Comment: I never heard that name before, but it is just an easy corollary of the comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

The integral of the above from 0 to $\frac{\pi}{2} is -\frac{\left( \pi \,\mathrm{log}\left( \frac{\pi }{2}\right) \,a-\pi \,\mathrm{log}\left( \frac{\pi }{2}\right) +\pi \right) \,{e}^{-\mathrm{log}\left( \frac{\pi }{2}\right) \,a}}{2\,{a}^{2}-4\,a+2}$ which is defined for all a<1

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the following integral with $n > 0$:
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x^{n - a}\,{\rm d}x
=
\left.{x^{n - a + 1} \over n - a + 1}\right\vert_{0}^{\pi/2}
=
{\left(\pi/2\right)^{n - a + 1} \over n - a + 1}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

Derive both members respect of $n$:
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x^{n - a}\ln\left(x\right)\,{\rm d}x
=
{\left(\pi/2\right)^{n - a + 1}\ln\left(\pi/2\right)\left(n - a + 1\right)
 -
 \left(\pi/2\right)^{n - a + 1}
 \over
 \left(n - a + 1\right)^{2}}
$$

Take the limit, in both members, $n \to 0^{+}$:
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\ln\left(x\right) \over x^{a}}\,{\rm d}x
=
{\left(\pi/2\right)^{-a + 1}\ln\left(\pi/2\right)\left(-a + 1\right)
 -
 \left(\pi/2\right)^{-a + 1}
 \over
 \left(-a + 1\right)^{2}}
$$

\begin{equation}
\color{#ff0000}{\large%
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\ln\left(x\right) \over x^{a}}\,{\rm d}x
\color{#000000}{\ =\ }
\left[%
{\ln\left(\pi/2\right) \over 1 - a} - {1 \over \left(1 - a\right)^{2}}
\right]
\left(\pi \over 2\right)^{1 - a}}
\tag{2}
\end{equation}

Notice that result $\left(1\right)$ requires $a < 1$ which keeps
$n - a + 1 > 0\,,\ \forall\ n > 0$. Then, result $\left(2\right)$ is valid whenever $\color{#ff0000}{\large a < 1}$.